# "Required parameter key not set" error in AWS ATHENA

Tags: sql, database, amazon-athena

I am using AWS ATHENA in my lambda function to query and fetch results.

For simpler queries, sometimes the query execution fails with error "Required parameter key not set"

But on re-execution, the query gets executed successfully.

For complex queries, the query never gets executed and fails with the same error "Required parameter key not set." These queries take more than 5 seconds to execute when queries in the Athena console of the AWS account.

What changes do I need to make to successfully execute Athena query from my lambda function? Below is the code.

```
def execute_query(query, athena_database, service_query_result_folder):
    # Function to execute the sql query and get the results.
    athena_client = boto3.client(service_name="athena", region_name=region)
    result_location = f"s3://{s3_bucket}/{service_query_result_folder}/"
    logger.info(f"Athena result location: {result_location}")
    execution_start_response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={"Database": athena_database},
        ResultConfiguration={"OutputLocation": result_location}
    )
    queryId = execution_start_response["QueryExecutionId"]
    logger.info(f"Executed query with execution id: {queryId}")
    result_file = queryId + ".csv"
    result_file_with_prefix = service_query_result_folder + '/' + result_file
    result_file_location = result_location + result_file
    execution_get_response = athena_client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=queryId)
    execution_details = execution_get_response["QueryExecution"]
    execution_status = execution_details["Status"]["State"]
    if execution_status == "SUCCEEDED":
        logger.info(f"Athena query execution {execution_status}. Execution details: {execution_details}")
        logger.info(f"Result file location: {result_file_location}")
        logger.info(f"Result fie: {result_file}")
        return result_file_with_prefix
    elif execution_status == "FAILED" or execution_status == "CANCELLED":
        logger.error("Athena query execution {}. Details: {}".format(execution_status, execution_get_response))
```

I tried updating the query to result with one row, but I'm still facing the issue.